# somehow not able to pass a value to a function leading to a typeError

Tags: javascript, dom, recursion, typeerror

I'm trying to re-implement the function getElementsByClassName. As part of my function I want to recursively call my function on an element's children w/ its own child nodes.

However, despite console logging that I'm passing a value w/ child nodes into the function, when I console log the element right after I recursively called it, it says my element is undefined and therefore it fails when I ask to get its child nodes.

Here's my code.

```
  var getElementsByClassName = function(className) {
  var results = [];
  function inner(element) {
    console.log(element); //eventually says undefined unexpectedly
    var children = element.childNodes;
    console.log(Array.isArray(children));
    for (var i = 0; i < children.length; i++){
    console.log("the class list is: ", children[i].classList);
    if (children[i].classList !== undefined){
      if (children[i].classList.value === className) {
        results.push(children[i]);
      }
    }
    console.log("the child nodes are: ", children[i].childNodes);
    if (children[i].childNodes.length !== 0){
      console.log("the one that's supposed to have child nodes is", children[i]); //lists an element w/ child nodes
      return inner(document[children[i]]);
      } 
    }
    return results;
  }
  return inner(document.body);
};  

console.log(getElementsByClassName("targetClassName"));
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName("targetClassName"))
```

Answer (score 0):

you are referring to document as object with property of element div, but it can't has such property

```
return inner(document[children[i]]);
```

should be

```
return inner(children[i]);
```

Comment: That didn't work. Gave me the error Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list. Yet the parentheses in ```return inner(children[i]]);``` are correct